# Hacky way of refreshing CursorAdapter cursor

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

Trying to refresh a `ListView` populated by `CursorAdapter`, I would have thought something like this would work:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter listAdapter;

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    listAdapter.swapCursor(listAdapter.getCursor());
}
```

In that it swaps cursor from old one to new one and the `ListView` gets the new data. Why doesn't this way work and what is the alternative?

Slightly more information, `swapCursor()` is supposed to return the old cursor but in the above it returns null.

EDIT:
I know why it doesn't work. `swapCursor()` checks if the new cursor and the old cursor are the same, if it is then it does nothing:

```
public Cursor swapCursor(Cursor newCursor) {
    if (newCursor == mCursor) {
        return null;
    }
```

And `changeCursor` calls `swapCursor` so can't use that. Now to hack that into working...

Comment: Have you tried `adapter.notiftyDataSetChanged()`?

Comment: @Vucko Yeah it didn't have an effect. Apparently it's called by swapping cursor too but I didn't see it in the code